# Согласование обобщающего слова с однородными

Tags: согласование

Помогите разобраться! В предложении с обобщающим словом однородные члены предложения стоят в том же падеже, что и обобщающее слово. Тогда почему в этом предложении — «В произведениях Паустовского можно найти много лесных слов: корабельная роща, осинник, мелколесье, бор, пустошь, чапыга» — обобщающее слово в винительном падеже, а однородные в именительном?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здесь в качестве обобщающего слова выступает группа "много лесных слов". Она действительно стоит в винительном падеже.  Но перечисление идет по названию слов, а не их значению. Здесь и нужен именительный ("назывной"). Винительный предполагал бы нахождение в тексте не слов, а самих объектов. Поставьте вокруг них кавычки - и все станет ясно:
***В произведениях Паустовского можно найти много лесных слов: [слова] "корабельная роща", "осинник", "мелколесье", "бор", "пустошь", "чапыга".***